# Проверка строки на пустоту

Tags: java, строки

Как можно проверить строку на содержание символов, что бы при чтении из файла игнорировать пустые строки. Я написал такой метод, но понимаю что должно быть что то проще и эффективнее.

```
public boolean checkForEmptiness(String check) {
char[] chars = check.toCharArray();
int spaceCount = 0;
for (char ch : chars) {
    if (ch == ' ') {
        a++;
    }
}
    if (a == chars.length) {
    return true; // Возвращает true если все знаки это пробел
    } else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для определения пустых строк можно воспользоватся простым условием вроде такого:

```
string.trim().length() == 0
```

Comment: Он \t \r \n тоже удаляет?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, да, конечно. `"\t \r \n".trim().length()` - возвращает 0. trim() удаляет из строки все символы, у которых [Character.isWhitespace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)) возвращает true.

Comment: Прежде, чем делать `trim()` я бы рекомендовал предварительно убедиться, что `string != null`

Comment: @IgorKudryashov, И что же в этом случае делать? Это Java, а не C++ - не надо так )). Здесь вызываемые методы обязанны проверять корректность параметров, которые им поданны. И trim() в описанном случае выдаст NullPointerException - это полностью корректное поведение в данной ситуации. Ни о каких "возращаем false если строка null" здесь и речи идти не должно. ))

Comment: @SergeyRufanov Как "что делать?" Человек же просил проверку строки на пустоту, т.о. если `string == null || string.trim().length()==0`, значит строка пустая. Без первой части проверки, да, есть возможность получить NPE и тогда уже придётся разбираться с ним отдельно. Либо использовать apache commons-lang, там подобные проверки уже встроены повсеместно.

Comment: @IgorKudryashov, если строка null - значит строка null, а вовсе не пустая. Не стоит приравнивать эти два понятия.

Answer (score 5):

Или же можно так проверить на пустоту:

1)

```
string.trim().isEmpty();
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--

2) При помощи библиотеки 
org.apache.commons.commons-lang3

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isEmpty(string);
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 1):

```
StringUtils.isBlank(yourString)
```

из пакета `org.apache.commons.lang3`

Answer (score -3):

```
(string+"").trim().length() == 0;
```